# How to prevent provider from auto disposing when using riverpod_generator

Tags: flutter, riverpod, riverpod-generator

I am using [`riverpod_generator`](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod_generator) and I don't see any way of keeping the provider alive. The generator code is actually equivalent to

```dart
final fooProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose((ref) async => 0);
```

But in above code I could remove `autoDispose` but how can I do that with `@riverpod` generator?

```dart
@riverpod
Future<int> foo(FooRef ref) async {
  return 0; // Where to define `autoDispose`? 
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All providers auto dispose when you generate them using the generator. But you can set `keepAlive` to change this behavior.

```dart
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
Future<int> foo(FooRef ref) async {
  return 0;
}
```