# After Riverpod state update on one widget, ref.watch doesn't trigger on my other widget

Tags: flutter, riverpod, riverpod-generator

I'm busy implementing a simple counter using riverpod. From the examples I've seen, the riverpod state is updated on one widget (by doing something like `ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).increment()`) and changes to state are watched on the same widget. When I try this it works as expected, using `ref.watch(counterProvider)` in the `build` method of the same widget. The counter is updated on the UI.

My problem comes in when I update the counter on one widget, and watch for changes to the counter state on another widget (these widgets are two different tabs in a TabView). So basically my increment button is on one tab, and the value of the counter is displayed on the next tab. In this scenario, the counter doesn't get updated.

The weird thing is, if I add a `ref.watch` on the same widget where I do the state update, the `ref.watch` on the second tab also starts working and updates the UI correctly on that tab.

Anyone know why this might be happening? Both of these widgets are `ConsumerStatefulWidget`s and my `ProviderScope` is at the root of my app. I'm using riverpod V2, with the code generation.

My provider:

```
part 'counter.provider.g.dart';

@riverpod
class Counter extends _$Counter {
  @override
  int build() {
    return 2;
  }

  void increment() {
    state++;
  }
}
```

First widget (state update):

```
ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).increment();
```

Second widget (state reading):

```
var x = ref.watch(counterProvider);
```

Comment: Please share full example of first and second widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providers annotated with `@riverpod` will be disposed automatically when it is not being watched or listened. It seems like your `counterProvider` is getting disposed when switching to another tab.

You can add a print statement to verify that.

```dart
@override
int build() {
  ref.onDispose(() {
    print('disposed');
  });
  return 2;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what was happening, thanks for your answer. I followed this answer to prevent it from being disposed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74123230/10570170

It seems weird that this is the default behaviour though right? It's not an uncommon use case to save state for later usage.

Comment: Yeah. Specifying the keepAlive to true will disable the auto dispose even the provider is not being watched or listened. One thing to keep in mind is that you should not set keepAlive to true for family providers to avoid memory leaks.